# How can I launch the splash screen only when the app is killed or started for the first time ?

Tags: android, screen, splash-screen

I don't know why but the splashscreen always starts. I would like it to start only when the app is killed or runs for the first time.

Here is my code :

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Thread splashscreen = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int sp = 0;
                    while(sp < 1000){
                        sleep(100);
                        sp = sp +100;
                    };

                }

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, TutoActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };

        splashscreen.start();
    }
```

Comment: i did'nt quite understand.it start everytime because you splash screen is your launcher activity. you don't want it to start from it?

Answer (score 1):

Your should start a new activity like bellow (In case user press back button and return to splash page)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

Since there can only be one launcher activity for a android application, therefore i don't think that your application is showing splash screen every time you minimize your app, if it is then the app is restarting while you resume it . Reason the app is still restarting instead of resuming is that the device which you are using is not having sufficient ram to hold your application and provide you a smooth multitasking experience .

**Solution**

You have to install your app in different device which have sufficient amount of ram to run you application . This should prevent your app from restarting even when you are minimizing it .

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the answer, but for good practice, never sleep the main thread.
you can use this to delay this instead of sleep.

```
int showSplashFor = 2500;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }, showSplashFor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the trick is to first call

```
finish()
```

and then

```
startActivity()
```

on your SplashScreenActivity, so it won't appear until you kill the app.